# Mongod exiting from VS Code integrated terminal but can run mongo command

Tags: mongodb, powershell, visual-studio-code, cmd

please help me out.
I have installed MongoDB on my system and I am trying to run mongod from integrated VS Code terminal. I have already installed MongoDB extension for VS Code and also added a connection.

On running mongod command from VS Code integrated terminal (cmd, powershell both), here is the error that I am having:

```
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.015+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling 
TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.018+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.026+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.029+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":4440,"port":27017,"dbPath":"D:/data/db/","architecture":"64-bit","host":"DESKTOP-AV18UQG"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.037+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23398,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Target operating system minimum version","attr":{"targetMinOS":"Windows 7/Windows Server 2008 R2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.039+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.4","gitVersion":"8db30a63db1a9d84bdcad0c83369623f708e0397","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"windows","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.039+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Microsoft Windows 10","version":"10.0 (build 19042)"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.041+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by 
command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.042+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in 
initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"NonExistentPath: Data directory D:\\data\\db\\ not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file."}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.044+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":10000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.045+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.045+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.057+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.058+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.058+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.060+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.060+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.061+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.062+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.062+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.075+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.076+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.077+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":4784926, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down full-time data capture"}
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.078+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}  
{"t":{"$date":"2021-04-02T14:14:26.078+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

I am not sure about why this is happening. I have a folder in C:/data/db and I have also added path variables in Environment System variables as well.

What is more startling to me is that I can run the command mongo from my integrated terminal and run all the commands. Please help me out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: it's looking for path `D:/data/db` check the error.

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar I also thought that was the error. I don't know why it is doing that. Can you please tell me what you think about it? One thing is that I have the project directory (from where I am running the terminal) is D Drive.

Comment: `mongod --dbpath path` or `mongod --config path`

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar I just tried this out. While mongod --dbpath does work, --config path does not work. It says Error: Opening config path, is a directory

Answer (score 1):

In D directory I just created a folder named data and inside of it I created another folder named db. Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what I was doing wrong. What I am trying to do is not allowed.
Here is what the docs say

> Start mongod Processes By default, MongoDB listens for connections
> from clients on port 27017, and stores data in the `/data/db` directory.
>
> On Windows, this path is on the drive from which you start MongoDB.
> For example, if you do not specify a `--dbpath`, starting a MongoDB
> server on the `C:\` drive stores all data files in `C:\data\db`.
>
> To start MongoDB using all defaults, issue the following command at
> the system shell:
>
> `mongod`

You can read more here:
[MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-processes)

If you want to run the same thing using a mongod command, you should make a .bat file to run the command for you. Here is how you do it:

1. Go to C:\Windows\System32
2. Make a .bat file there and name it mongod.bat (you might need to have administrator privileges for that.
3. Put the following command in .bat file:

```
start /b call "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin\mongod.exe"  --dbpath "C:\data\db"
```

4. Save the file (again you need admin privileges)
5. Restart VS Code and try running mongod command. You will be good to go.